# Java calculation run-time error （using factorial to calculate Euler's number)

Tags: java

I'm trying to calculate the Euler's number.
As the Euler's number `e = 1 + (1/1!) + (1/2!) + (1/3!) + ..... = 2.718281828....`
where n! equals to the factorial of n.
First I wrote a class `Factorial.class` to calculate to factorial:

File `Factorial.java`

```
public class Factorial
{
//Methods
//If statement to abolish negative integer parameter have to be filled
     public static int factorial(int number)
     {
          if (number == 0 || number == 1)
          {
               return 1;
          } else
          {
               int m = number;
               for (int i = number - 1; i > 1; i--)
               {
                    m = m * i;
               }
               return m;
          }
     }
}
```

This class works fine with a testing class `FactorialTest.class`

File `FactorialTest.java`

```
public class FactorialTest
{
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
          System.out.println(Factorial.factorial(10));
     }
}
```

This class prints 3628800

Later I create a `EulersNumber.class` to print the value of e:

File `EulersNumber.java`

```
public class EulersNumber
{
     public static void main(String[] args)
     {
          double e = 1;
          for (int i = 1; i > 10000; i++)
          {
               double j = (double)(Factorial.factorial(i));
               double k = 1 / j;
               e = e + k;
          }
          System.out.println("e = " + e); //e = 1.0
     }
}
```

The value of e should be 2.718281828.... but this class prints e = 1.0

Where did I make a mistake?

Comment: Have you tried to debug it? Say, output `i` at each step of the loop?

Comment: `for (int i = 1; i < 10000; i++)`

Comment: I‘d tried to debug it. At the beginning it is full of bugs, I debug them and stucks here. Thanks

Comment: Calculating the factorial from scratch every time is very inefficient you can calculate it in the loop as you go.  Also once the factorial is less than 1e-16 * the value you are adding to, it will make no difference and you can stop.  This is likely to be about 16! (not 10000!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The loop only executes when `i > 10000.`

replace

```
for (int i = 1; i > 10000; i++)
```

with

```
for (int i = 1; i< 10000; i++)
```

Answer (score 4):

```
for (int i = 1; i > 10000; i++)
```

There is a problem in the above line. The loop only executes if `i > 10000`. But `i` starts at 1. So it never executes.

BTW, you won't be able to use `int` to represent the factorial of `10000`, which is an incredibly large number, well beyond of the limit of int (which is `2^32 - 1`). Use BigInteger instead.

Comment: I recommend `double` for the factorial for performance reasons. `10000!` could take a long time to compute otherwise

Comment: double is not precise for large numbers.

Comment: You don't need much precision here. You're just adding its inverse to some double.

Answer (score 2):

In the for loop, the condition is > and must be <

Code:

```
for(int i = 0;i < 10000 ; i++)
```

Why didn´t make the factorial method recursive?

```
public static int factorial(int number)
 {
      if (number < 2)
      {
           return 1;
      } else
      {
           return number * factorial(number-1);
      }
 }
```